# multichoose but limit the duplicates

Tags: combinatorics

"n choose k" is how many combinations of: k-sized elements from n unique choices.

"n multichoose k" is how many k-sized elements from n choices, where full multiplicity is allowed (that is, {a, b, c} choose 3 can have {a, a, a}).

How do we calculate "n choose k by m" where we allow only *m* duplicates?

Comment: What do you mean by $n$ choose $k$ by $m$?

Comment: Do you mean that *each* of $ab,c$ can occur a maximum of $m$ times ?